# Getting Curl to work in a Script

Tags: shell-script, curl

I have a curl command to download a file

If I put it in a DOS Batch file...it works fine

(i'm altering the security parts)

```
@Echo On
REM This is close to the final version to be used 
REM first file
curl --verbose -g -o "N:\csas_file1.txt" "https://myschool.academicworks.com/api/v1/disbursements.csv?c[]=initial_application_category_name__contains__Offered__contains__Accepted&c[]=opportunity_archived__eq__0&page=1&per_page=1000&fields=award_period_name,user_uid,portfolio_code,disbursement_amount&token=securitytoken"
@PAUSE
```

However, if I try this in a script I get an error 400 *Bad request*

```
curl --verbose -g -o '/mnt/itfiletrans/csas_file1.txt' 'https://myschool.academicworks.com/api/v1/disbursements.csv?c[]=initial_application_category_name__contains__Offered__contains__Accepted&c[]=opportunity_archived__eq__0&page=1&per_page=1000&fields=award_period_name,user_uid,portfolio_code,disbursement_amount&token=securitytoken'
```

any clue as to what is causing the 400 in the second one which is called from Atomic/UC4?

Comment: How are you inputting the security token?  Also did you write the "script" on windows?  If so make sure it doesn't have crlf line endings (run `dos2unix` on it).

Comment: The security token is in the script...I didn't include it on this public forum for...security reasons...

yes I wrote it in windows...I'll try the dos2unix on it..